# Yahoo finance message board,how to post message on Yahoo message board?

Tags: yahoo

does Yahoo provide web service to post message on the message board ? [yahoo messages](http://messages.yahoo.com/yahoo/Business___Finance/)

I try to find but seem yahoo not provide any web service API for it ,

anyone can help ...

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such service. The Message Boards are designed for interactive users rather than automated scripts.